# Java. Abstract elements list. How to determine element type

Tags: java, oop

I have basic abstract class:

```
 abstract class Graphic 
 {
 abstract void draw(Graphics g);
 }
```

I have Group class which helps to group elements into particular groups. Notice that this Group class can have other Group elements inside itself.

```
 class Group extends Graphic
 {
     private ArrayList<Graphic> children = new ArrayList<Graphic>();
 public ArrayList<Graphic> getChildren() 
 {
      return children;
 }

 public void setChildren(ArrayList<Graphic> children) 
 {
          this.children = children;
 }

 public void draw(Graphics g)
 {
     for(Graphic child:children)
     {
          child.draw(g);
     }
 }
 }
```

Here is the line class which also extends Graphic.

```
 class Line extends Graphic  {
     private Point startPoint = new Point(0,0);
 private Point endPoint = new Point(1,1);

 public void draw(Graphics g) 
 {
     g.drawLine(startPoint.x, startPoint.y, endPoint.x, cendPoint.y);
 }
 }
```

I can add Line element or another Group element into Group class children list, that is I can group the groups and these groups can have their own groups too and every group can have line element too, however I'm unable to determine whether the child element is Group or Line. How can I determine whether the element is Group or Line?

Comment: If you are using oop properly you shouldn't need to know. What is it you need to do that makes you believe you need to treat specific objects in a special way?

Comment: why dont you just use `instanceof`

Comment: OldCurmudgeon let's say that Group class has additional methods that class Line don't have.

Comment: @Benas What about those methods? Why should a parent know about their children in detail?

Comment: @Benas Line inherits those methods, so it has those methods as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`instanceof` operator or compare `object.getClass()` object. 
But checking concrete type of object is not good practice. 
You should depend only on public interface (your `Graphic`)

Comment: BTW: If you have two seperate Classloaders (X and Y) and both load's the same class, a instance of the Class of first Classloader(X) is not an Instance of the same Class from the Classloader(Y)!

Comment: @PeterRader : Check class name then :) ( full name with package)

Answer (score 2):

Use `instanceof` or reflection:

```
public void draw(Graphics g) 
{
   for(Graphic child:children)
   {
      child.draw(g);

      if (child instanceof Line) {
         System.out.println("child is of type Line");
      }

      System.out.printf("child is of type %s%n", child.getClass());
   }
 }
```

But you should not need it except for debugging. If you do you better check your design again.

Few more things:

- Do not use `ArrayList` except to specify implementation, use `List` instead (this allows switching implementation say to `LinkedList` by changing a single line)
- If `Graphics` provides no implementation, use interface instead of an abstract class (a class can inherit only one class, but it can implement multiple interfaces)